# autocomplete search bar at runtime

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i am trying to make autocomplete search in codeigniter, but the problem is that the list opened at first time when user write in input field but did not changed according to the user input. it occur only at first time.

here is my code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#text').keyup( function() {
    var min_length = 0; 
    var keyword = $('#text').val();
    if (keyword.length >= min_length) {
      $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost/new/index.php/travels/search_fields',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { term: $("#text").val()},
        success: function(data) {
          $.each(data, function() {
            $.each(this, function(k, v) {
              $("#demo").append("<li>" + v + "</li>");
            });
          });
        }
      });
    } else {
      $('#demo').hide();
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

and the query is :

```
function search_field($country_id){
    $this->db->distinct();
    $this->db->select("destination");
    $this->db->from('travels_detail');
    $this->db->like('destination', $country_id);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
```

Comment: - 1 - Can you fold properly your code please :) I can't edit because an edit is in pending.

- 2 - I'm not sure of your code in php, which db do you use ? The `like` might be with '%' to signal that the string is not finished. `$this->db->like('destination', $country_id.'%');`

- 3 - Can you console.log the result of $each(data, ...) ? It will help.

- 4 - `$("#demo").append`, so you append and you never clear `$('#demo')` ?

Answer (score 0):

You're actually touching on some of the most challenging issues with AJAX here, namely the problem of canceling requests and the fact that requests can complete in any order.

Lets say the user types '123' in the search field. You would then send out three requests: '1', '12', and '123'.

At this point in time you're no longer interested in the results of the first 2 requests. However as it turns out, writing code that properly handles this can be tricky. Another problem is that the requests may complete in *any* order. For example let's say the requests complete in the reverse order (3rd, 2nd, 1st). You would then probably end up displaying only the results for the 1st request, not the 3rd one which is what you actually want.

One step on the way to handling this is by using [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). You can find a great introduction to that topic [here](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/promises). A great solution for this kind of problem is the [RxJS](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS) library. This is an excellent library that, among other things, lets you handle asynchronous collections as streams. There's even an [autocomplete example](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/tree/master/examples/autocomplete) in the RxJS repository. However Rx is a huge library with lots of functions and several new concepts, which is it may be best to start with getting a feel for Promises first.